# Woocommerce Product Category and Subcategory dropdown select

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am setting up a wordpress site with woocommerce.
i have my products arranged in categories and subcategories 
eg. car brand > car > year of manufacturing > products

i wanted to have a simple form at home page to select category and each subcategories that eventually leads users to the product.
when i choose car brand, the car dropdown only shows selection of cars of that brand; and after i choose car, the year dropdown only shows the available selection of that car.

I tried to look for plugin, but i cannot find any suitable one.
how should i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should keep this simple. Limit it to main category and sub category (Car Brand > Car Model) 
Then make custom attribute called year. Each product (car) will have year attribute which will appear in filters.

I use these two filters (depending on design):

[WooCommerce Products Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-filter/)

[Themify – WooCommerce Product Filter](https://wordpress.org/plugins/themify-wc-product-filter/)

I hope this helped.

(remember to expand this a little more - year is not the only attribute you can use. Colours, engine size, number of doors and so on...)